# React boilerplate doesn't load js files in the index.html

Tags: javascript, reactjs, boilerplate

I'm testing React-boilerplate and I'm trying to load some javascript files in the `app/index.html` file:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- The first thing in any HTML file should be the charset -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <!-- Make the page mobile compatible -->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- Allow installing the app to the homescreen -->
    <link rel="manifest" href="manifest.json">
    <meta name="mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">

    <script type="text/javascript" src="myJScriptFile1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="myJScriptFile2.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- Display a message if JS has been disabled on the browser. -->
    <noscript>If you're seeing this message, that means <strong>JavaScript has been disabled on your browser</strong>, please <strong>enable JS</strong> to make this app work.</noscript>

    <!-- The app hooks into this div -->
    <div id="app"></div>
    <!-- A lot of magic happens in this file. HtmlWebpackPlugin automatically includes all assets (e.g. bundle.js, main.css) with the correct HTML tags, which is why they are missing in this HTML file. Don't add any assets here! (Check out webpackconfig.js if you want to know more) -->
  </body>
</html>
```

This is the default `index.html` file. I'm running it with `npm` or `yarn` and the server console shows me no error, but my browser console keeps telling me:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
```

Just like this, there is no more error. These javascript files work fine because I'm using them into another React based project, and I'm calling them into the `index.html` file as well. The console prints that error per file. If I trace the error it leads me to the correspond .js file.

After almost a week searching the web I couldn't find a solution. So that's it, does anybody have any idea on how to solve this?

Comment: I suspect you're requesting missing resource, thus returning a 404-html page.

Comment: @Caramiriel it was a misstyping... but it doesn't matter due to the myJScriptFile1.js returns the same error as well.

Comment: Can you post your js code?

Comment: Didn't I post my code?

Comment: That is just your `index.html`.

Comment: what is the point posting the js code? I need a way to load it. I  think I need a little bit more research in webpack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I'm answering myself. I needed a little bit more of research in webpack. I achieve this through webpack:

installed `npm i add-asset-html-webpack-plugin -D`

then, in the webpack config file, under plugins I added:

`new AddAssetHtmlPlugin({ filepath: require.resolve('./some-file') })`

and that's it.